# Error when setting up a modding workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm trying to load up a Minecraft Modding workspace. When I load up ForgeMDK, and run `gradlew setUpDecompWorkspace eclipse`, the 'Build' is successful.When I try to load "MDKExample" in eclipse, I get

> The project description file (.project) for 'MDKExample' is missing.  This file contains important information about the project.  The project will not function properly until this file is restored.

I've tried resetting, `--refresh-dependencies` and re-running `gradlew setUpDecompWorkspace eclipse`.

When I use gradle's 'clean' command, and then the command as two commands (`gradlew setUpDecompWorkspace gradlew eclipse`), it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run those two commands individually. First do

```
gradlew setupDecompWorkspace
```

without "eclipse". When your build is finished run

```
gradlew eclipse
```

When this is finished as well you should be able to open up your project. Remember to point your workspace to the .eclipse folder!

(You might need to extract a fresh copy of the MDK, your command might have messed up some things. Happened to me atleast...)